# Sql select to array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a sql request

```
select array(select distinct request_at from trip) as datas;
with q as (select sum(case when request_at = datas[1] then 1 else 0 end) as total from trip)
select * from q
```

I'm trying to create a massive of datas from select and then use it for my future requests, but i have error "datas isn't exist". How should change my request to get this work.

Comment: Please add tables with data and wanted result a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Try Simple Query, without Array

```
SELECT request_at, COUNT(*) as total
FROM trip
GROUP BY request_at;
```

And here is With Array

```
WITH datas AS (
  SELECT array_agg(distinct request_at) as request_dates
  FROM trip
), counts AS (
  SELECT unnest(request_dates) as request_date, COUNT(*) as total
  FROM trip, datas
  WHERE request_at = ANY(datas.request_dates)
  GROUP BY unnest(request_dates)
)
SELECT * FROM counts;
```